# Is there a way to make Google Notifier (version 1.10.4) check my gmail more often?

Tags: gmail

It checks every ten minutes, and I want it to check every minute. I'm on unix.

Comment: Please indicate the operating system as well.

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and paste:

```
defaults write com.google.GmailNotifier AutocheckInterval 1
```